# Symfony 3 - CAS authentication is imposed on me as soon as I want to subscribe to the site

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I work under symfony 3 with two modes of connection.
One is in-memory (database), and the other by CAS authentication.

So when you come to the homepage of the site, you have to be able to choose whether to connect thanks to the database (with the form already present on the homepage) or with the CAS authentication (and in this case case we are redirected to the authentication page).

The problem is that if I'm not connected, then if I try to access the home page (or another page of the site), I am automatically redirected to the CAS authentication page. I therefore no longer have the option to display the homepage that must be displayed when not logged in, with the login form for registered users in the database.

I use a bundle created by a colleague.

**My security.yml:**

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        app:
           id: bes_auth.user_provider

    firewalls:

        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
           # anonymous:    true

        main:
            logout_on_user_change: true
            pattern: ^/

            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - app.security.login_form_authenticator
                    - bes_auth.authenticator

                entry_point: Site\PagesBundle\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator

            logout:
                path:   deconnexion #nom de la route de déconnexion
                target: /
                success_handler: bes_auth.authenticator
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:

        #    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        #   - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        #  - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/.*, role: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/profile/.*, role: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/logout, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

**config.yml:**

```
# FOS User Bundle
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Site\PagesBundle\Entity\User
    service:
        mailer: fos_user.mailer.twig_swift
    registration:
        form:
            type: FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType
            name: fos_user_registration_form
            validation_groups: [Registration, Default]
        confirmation:
            enabled: true
            template: '@FOSUser/Registration/email.txt.twig'
    profile:
        form:
            type: FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\ProfileFormType
            #validation_groups: [Profile, Default]
    resetting:
        email:
            template: '@FOSUser/Resetting/email.txt.twig'
    group:
        group_class: FosSf3\MainBundle\Entity\Group
    from_email:
        address: *********
        sender_name: ******


besancon_auth:
    use_default_provider : true
    user_entity: ~
    homepage: "homepage"
    authentication_service: Site\PagesBundle\Security\Auth\AuthCasService
    type_auth: Cas
    cas:
        #Serveur Cas
        hostname: ***********
        #Port Cas
        port: ****
        #Uri Cas
        uri: ""
```

Would this be related to the line in config.php: `homepage: "homepage"` ??
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If we read your access_control, we can see that you cannot go further than "/" without being authenticated fully.

So you have to authorize your path to the homepage **before** the access control to "/"
So something like this :

```
access_control:

    #    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    #   - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    #  - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/.*, role: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/profile/.*, role: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/logout, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Though i'm not sure what the path to your homepage if it's **/homepage** or just **/** so just adjust your access_control depending on what you want.

Comment: Hey, so, my homepage is : /
So I added : - { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
Is it correct ?
With that, the problem is the same, unfortunately

Comment: Ok I will try now

Comment: Oh, the problem is the same :(

Comment: Could this come from the code in the bundle which by default uses this same route as a route to redirect to CAS authentication? And in this case, he would take over the access_control?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191843/discussion-between-dylan-kas-and-eronn).

Comment: Indeed, by removing acces_control, the problem is always the same. So it would come from the code itself that defines this route for authentication?